Construct a counterexample of Quasi-central Armendariz which is not central Armendariz
Central Armendariz ring : A ring $R$ is said to be central Armendariz if whenever $f(x),g(x)\in R[x]$ satisfy $f(x)g(x)=0$ then $a_ib_j\in Z(R),\forall 0\leq i \leq n, 0\leq j \leq m $, where $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{i=n}a_ix^i$ and $g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{j=m}b_jx^j$.
Quasi central Armendariz ring : A ring $R$ is said to be Quasi central Armendariz if whenever $f(x),g(x)\in R[x]$ satisfy $f(x)g(x)=0$ then $Ra_ib_j=a_ib_jR,\forall 0\leq i \leq n, 0\leq j \leq m $, where $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{i=n}a_ix^i$ and $g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{j=m}b_jx^j$.
I want to construct two polynomials in a Quasi central Armendariz ring such that $f(x)g(x)=0$ but $a_ib_j \notin Z(R)$ for some $a_i,b_j$.
My attempt : It is presented in literature that $T_2(\mathbb{Z_n})$ is Quasi central Armendariz whenever $n$ is not square free natural number. Here $T_2(R)$ represents upper triangular matrix ring over $R$. Suppose I take $R=\mathbb{Z_5}$ then $T_2(\mathbb{Z_5})$ is Quasi central Armendariz, now can you help me to construct two polynomials whose product is zero, is there any trick to always construct two polynomials whose product is zero.
